# Change background image after purchased

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am setting background image in a ViewController demo version.  After purchase or Buy something using in app purchase, i want to change background image.

background image in `ViewController1.m` and in app purchase in `ViewController2.m`.

How to pass the value from `ViewController2.m` to `ViewController1.m` to change the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a value in userdefaults in viewcontroller2 after purchasing. Then check this value in viewcontroller1 and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSNotificationCenter. add observer in ViewController1.m's viewDidLoad

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeBackground) name:kChangeBGNotification object:nil];
```

do the changes in -(void)changeBackground method

post the notification in ViewController2.m's

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kChangeBGNotification object: managedObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example to pass values between viewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        ShareMeU *destVieController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destVieController.backgorndImageName =@"image.png"
}
```

You can get this values in `viewDidLoad` method.